# Eclipse and Tomcat cannot run as server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have installed Tomcat and Eclipse Juno (downloaded as androids ADT). I have created a Server in eclipse without any errors, bur when I try to run my Java servlet as a server Eclipse prompts me to choose what server to use and to type in a Server Name. The thing is that the field where i am supposed to put the Server name is locked. I can put my cursor there, but I can not type anything. Since this field is empty, I cannot continue to run my Servlet. I tried to edit my org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs and my org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs files, but I could'nt find any of those files in ~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/. Is this a Eclipse bug, how do I run my servlet with my Tomcat setup?

Answer (score 1):

Go into Eclipse --> Preferences --> Servers --> Runtime Environment .

Remove the Tomcat version from there and then re-add the server through, new --> Servers.

This can occur with a corrupt server profile.

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes quite late, but anyway in can be helpful for people struggling same problem and came through this question.
If you are using eclipse on linux, try to run it as root, e.g.

```
sudo your/path/to/ecpise/folder/eclipse
```

and repeat your workaround.